# How to groupby multiple dataframes into an aggregated table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I load data using

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = load_data() 
# y_train here has a string class name inside
```

then I use encoder from sklearn to change my data to categorical

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

Data example

```
y_train = ["tomato","strawberry", "strawberry",  "potato", "strawberry",  "potato", "lemon"]
y_test = ["strawberry", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon"]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
print(y_train)
>>>[3 2 2 1 2 1 0]
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)
print(y_test)
>>>[2 0 0 0]
```

I can call `encoder.inverse_transform(y_test)` to get strings back

How to build a summary table to show a table like

```
Label     | y_train_count | y_test_count
----------+---------------+-------------
strawberry| 3             | 1
potato    | 2             | 0
...       | ...           | ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply compile lists into a Pandas data frame then aggregate with `groupby` (for long reporting) and `pivot_table` (for wide reporting).

**Compilation**

```py
# COMPILE EACH LIST INTO COLUMN WITH INDICATORS
y_train = ["tomato","strawberry", "strawberry",  "potato", "strawberry",  "potato", "lemon"]
y_test = ["strawberry", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon"]

categ_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'source': 'y_train', 'category': y_train}),
                      pd.DataFrame({'source': 'y_test', 'category': y_test})])

categ_df
#      source    category
# 0   y_train      tomato
# 1   y_train  strawberry
# 2   y_train  strawberry
# 3   y_train      potato
# 4   y_train  strawberry
# 5   y_train      potato
# 6   y_train       lemon
# 7    y_test  strawberry
# 8    y_test       lemon
# 9    y_test       lemon
# 10   y_test       lemon
```

**Aggregation**

```py
all_vals = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                [categ_df['category'].unique(), categ_df['source'].unique()]
           )
                               
agg_df = (categ_df.groupby(['category', 'source'])
                  .agg(count=('category', 'size'))
                  .reindex(all_vals, axis='index')
                  .fillna(0)
         )
agg_df
#                     count
# tomato     y_train    1.0
#            y_test     0.0
# strawberry y_train    3.0
#            y_test     1.0
# potato     y_train    2.0
#            y_test     0.0
# lemon      y_train    1.0
#            y_test     3.0

agg_df = (categ_df.assign(key=1)
                  .pivot_table(index='category', columns='source',
                               values='key', aggfunc='count')
                  .reindex(categ_df['source'].unique(), 
                           axis='columns')
                  .fillna(0)
         )
agg_df
# source      y_test  y_train
# category
# lemon          3.0      1.0
# potato         0.0      2.0
# strawberry     1.0      3.0
# tomato         0.0      1.0
```

Comment: That makes the trick! However, it is not simple for me. Could you tell me how to learn it, or how did you learn it, not to ask it again here?

Comment: As explained, ultimately your question is how to compile and aggregate data, (ie.,  count by groups). So learn how to compile data with `DataFrame` and `concat` and how to aggregate with `groupby` and `pivot_table`. The other `reindex` was to cleanup columns and indices. Read docs, tutorials,especially these [pandas user guides](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/), and best of all learn by doing! Pandas is a very popular tag on StackOverflow. Likely any error/undesired results were already asked in different form. So use search past Q's here! Happy coding!